# sql pivot function using date as a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have below table:

```
FP_SITE     ETL_LOAD_DATE  
---------      
20          6/30/2016
40          6/30/2016
10          7/8/2016
20          7/8/2016
10          7/8/2016
10          7/14/2016
20          11/10/2016
30          11/10/2016
30          11/17/2016
30          11/17/2016
```

and i want the out put to be as below:

```
Row        6/30/2016    7/8/2016    7/14/2016   11/10/2016  11/17/2016
10                         2            1       
20             1           1                        1   
30                                                  1          2
40             1
```

i tried to use pivot function but it didn't work, i used below code:

select * from 
 ( 
 select fp_site, trunc(etl_load_date)
from etl_fb_site
) 
 pivot
(
count(trunc(etl_load_date))
for to_char(etl_load_date, 'YYYY')in '2017'
)
order by trunc(etl_load_date);

it respond with [1]: ORA-01738: missing IN keyword. i'm not sure where is the problem, but i assume it is with to_char function, coz i tried the same code with text columns (string in IN clause), and it works fine. Note i'm using Oracle 11G.

below is the code to create the table:

```
create table etl_fb_site 
(FP_SITE number, ETL_LOAD_DATE date);

INSERT ALL
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (20  , TO_DATE('6/30/2016 20:05', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (40  , TO_DATE('6/30/2016 20:05', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (10  , TO_DATE('7/8/2016 10:03', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (20  , TO_DATE('7/8/2016 10:05', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (10  , TO_DATE('7/8/2016 10:10', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (10  , TO_DATE('7/14/2016 20:06', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (20  , TO_DATE('11/10/2016 21:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (30  , TO_DATE('11/10/2016 21:20', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (30  , TO_DATE('11/17/2016 20:33', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
into etl_fb_site(FP_SITE,ETL_LOAD_DATE)values (30  , TO_DATE('11/17/2016 21:33', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'))
select * from dual
```

Thanks,

Comment: The problem is that the `IN` clause of the `PIVOT` operator doesn't work like you seem to think it works. It does not work on some undefined set of values (to become column headers), obtained as the result of other processing. Pivoting works only with a pre-defined number of values in the IN clause, of pre-defined data types. What you seem to want to do can be done using dynamic SQL (generally not recommended) but it can't be done in "standard" SQL.